# Reading an XML file in PHP and store the values in an array

Tags: php, xml

I m just a beginner in PHP. Just want to make sure what I am doing is correct or am i complicating things or is there is any alternative in ajax

I have to read an xml file in php and store it in an array for further evaluation

The XML File is

```
> <IntervalReading>
>     <cost>907</cost>
>     <timePeriod>
>         <duration>900</duration>
>         <start>1330580700</start>
>          <!-- 3/1/2012 5:45:00 AM  -->
>     </timePeriod>
>     <value>302</value> </IntervalReading> <IntervalReading>
>     <cost>907</cost>
>     <timePeriod>
>         <duration>900</duration>
>         <start>1330581600</start>
>          <!-- 3/1/2012 6:00:00 AM  -->
>     </timePeriod>
>     <value>302</value> </IntervalReading> <IntervalReading>
>     <cost>907</cost>
>     <timePeriod>
>         <duration>900</duration>
>         <start>1330582500</start>
>          <!-- 3/1/2012 6:15:00 AM  -->
>     </timePeriod>
>     <value>302</value> </IntervalReading>
```

The PHP code for reading this data is

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->load( "tmp/".$filename ); $employees = array(); $value = array(); $cost =         array(); $start =     array();    $duration = array(); $doc->formatOutput = true; $employees = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "IntervalReading" );    foreach( $employees as $employee )  {
    $names = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "value" ); 
    $val =  $value[] = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $costs = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "cost" ); 
    $cost[] =  $costs->item(0)->nodeValue;  
    $startnames = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "start" ); 
    $start[] = $startnames  ->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $durations  = $employee->getElementsByTagName( "duration" );
    $duration[] = $durations->item(0)->nodeValue;  } }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Sorry, cannot execute your example. The XML data as posted is invalid (mixed up nodes, no root element). Your code yields syntax error.

Comment: plz check now..i have reposted it

Answer (score 2):

I usually use php SimpleXML for this purpose:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

It can read xml structure from string and returns nice object.

Comment: That's it basic usage here http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php